# Registrar fechas al actualizar una bitácora en PHP

Tags: php

Al tratar de hacer un ***UPDATE*** a una bitácora quiero registrar la `fecha_salida` y `hora_salida`.

Sin embargo, no me hace la actualización. En lugar de eso, me ingresa la `fecha_entrada` y `hora_entrada` bien pero al finalizar la sesión no me actualiza los datos.

Este es el código:

```
<?php

 session_start();
 include '../conexion/conexion.php';

 $id = $_SESSION['id'];

 $fecha = date("Y-m-d");
 $hora = date("H:i:s");

 $sql2="UPDATE bitacora SET fecha_salida='$fecha', hora_salida='$hora' WHERE 
 fk_usuario='$id'";
 $result2=mysql_query($sql2,$link);

 session_destroy();
 ?>
```

Comment: Que error te aparece?

Comment: ninguno, no me actualiza

Comment: Puedes usar ´ mysql_error()´ despues de ´$result2´, para determinar que error te arroja, asi sera mas facil ayudarte

Comment: print  mysql_error();

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: id in 
       C:\xampp\htdocs\audiomaster2017\administrador\salir.php on line 6`

Comment: Has un ´var_dump($id)´, con esta funcion podras determinar que valor tiene esa variable, asi compruebas si el problema esta en esa variable

Comment: el valor es null

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57970/discussion-between-ivan-botero-and-yoclens).

Comment: La variable `$id = $_SESSION['id'];` no tiene en realidad **nada** que se llame `id`, de ahí el error. Por otra parte, estás usando funciones `mysql_.*` obsoletas. Del [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php): _Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL._

Comment: Utiliza [edit] para añadir información.